# iFrame link changes not saved in CRM 2011

Tags: iframe, crm

We have a CRM 2011 on premise environment.
Our problem is that we can't edit any links in an iframe.
Nor with the unmanaged solution neither via the customizations.
Every time we confirm the changes, it just ignores them.

Yours sincerely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you can't change the iframe source url, or that interaction of things within the iframe don't work as expected?

Anyway, if it is the first problem, I had this happen to me and baffle me for a good few hours before I tried to change it (by accident) in a different browser.

Apparently some of the 2011 javascripts are very optimized for IE (or, in other words, broken in most browsers except IE ;-)

That were a few hours of my life I'll never get back, so hopefully this works for you too.

When CRM is concerned (or any mickeysoft web based application) try it in IE if your default browser doesn't work as expected. =)

HTH,

bovako